# bootrsp function unknown to Matlab

Tags: matlab, statistics-bootstrap

I try to execute a simple matlab bootstrapt example from taken [this guide](https://www.google.com.tr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB4QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fextras.springer.com%2F2006%2F978-3-540-35487-1%2FClop%2Fchallenge_objects%2Fpackages%2FRandomForest%2Fbootman.pdf&ei=vu3eVICwFsn-ygOnn4HgCA&usg=AFQjCNG6OhIcvEtvWSmYCTq8gWeFTnRlDw). The guide says that

```
>> x=1:5;
>> out=bootrsp(x,10)
   out = 2 5 5 5 2 3 2 3 4 1
         5 5 3 4 1 5 4 1 1 5
         5 3 1 3 1 5 3 5 3 1
         1 4 5 3 3 2 5 3 5 4
         3 3 5 3 5 1 5 3 5
```

When I run this command on command window, I get an error via `Undefined function or method 'bootrsp' for input arguments of type 'double'.` How can I add/load it?

Comment: This manual is extremely old, and is no doubt outdated. Is the `bootstrp` command what you're looking for? Try typing `help bootstrp` for more information about it.

Comment: `bootstrp` is in the Statistics toolbox, so you need to make sure you have license for it.

Comment: I try to learn bootstrapt method using matlab. Thank you, "help bootstrp" command   looks like enough how I use matlab bootstrapt function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Abdelhak M. Zoubir and D. Robert Iskander created once a "BOOTSTRAP MATLAB TOOLBOX", that is a private library for computing bootstraping statistics. This library required Matlab 5.0 and the Statistical Matlab Toolbox of this time. It contained a file called bootrsp.m.

You can read about it and download the file it from [here](http://www.spg.tu-darmstadt.de/res/dl/bootstraptoolboxformatlab/bootstrapmatlabtoolbox.en.jsp). It may still run.

However nowadays bootstrapping is inbuilt in Matlab (`bootstrp`), so there is probably no real need anymore to use it.